# Compile errors when compiling ServiceStack.Text.MonoTouch

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, servicestack

Has anyone been able to get the monotouch version of servicestack.text to compile? I am getting the following 2 errors.

- 'Application Name is not set in iOS Application Property Page'
- 'Identifier is not set in iOS Application Property Page'

Thanks

Comment: Those are generally warnings (and default values are supplied). Can you edit your question to show the **exact** errors from the Build Log (inside the Errors pad) ?

Answer (score 2):

Those errors are not directly related to ServiceStack but the MonoTouch project setup. They can be set in the project settings of the solution.

However, if you want to use ServiceStack.Text in MonoTouch you should use the Portable Class Library (PCL) version of ServiceStack.Text. It is available [from NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Text.Pcl):

> PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Text.Pcl

Then you simply include it as a reference in your project.